# Remove the AVPlayerViewController from the wkwebview after it plays an inline video

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, avplayerviewcontroller

So I have wkwebview which displays an html text that includes video urls as well. On tapping the video thumbnail, the wkwebview launches the AVPlayer to play the video just fine. But after viewing the video, I need to remove the player so that other information on the wkWebview is visible.But the player makes the wkwebview go blank. I am attaching the screenshots
 1. normal article with text and video thumbnail(calendar icon)
 2. Video being played normally
 3. After video being played, the rest of the wkwebview going blank.

I want to get back to state 1 from 3.[image]

[image: 1. normal article with text and video thumbnail(calendar icon)]

[image]

Comment: "I need to remove the player" You mean by changing the HTML? You can do that.

Comment: Hey Matt @matt can you help with some code?